# Is it possible to access the underlying pointer from a given iterator to a vector?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a vector defined as `vector<char>`, and I have some function which gets called at some point that receives a range - something like the following:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator& start, Iterator& end)
{
}
```

In the above function, I currently have a call to `std::find` to look for a given character - this is way too slow (I know this because I have profiled - :) ). What I'd like to do (at some point in the future is to use the SSE4.2 intrinsics to search for the character), but right now, what I want to do is a vector search, i.e. something like the following (not safe operation).

```
unsigned long long* scanv = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(<access pointer at start>);
// some byte magic.
```

so my question is - is the only way to do this is to also pass the vector as well and then do a `distance`, then `&vect[index]` to access the underlying pointer?

Comment: Incidentally, rather than a `vector<char>`, have you considered using a `string`?  `string::find()` may be optimised for this sort of thing.

Comment: How dare you profile before making optimization plans! You're suppose to just start them, without plans and without guidance, then wonder why your program is broken, messy, and impossible to fix; get it right. :)

Comment: @Oli, yes, the underlying `strchr` has been optimised for SSE4.2, however currently I don't have access to a core (and the appropriate glibc version) that supports this, and I'm replacing using `std::string` with `vector` because other operations (copying into, removing, searching for sequences etc.) appear to be significantly faster...

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the iterators `start` and `end` by reference? That's rather unusual in C++.

Comment: @Fred, yes in this case I want to, reason being that on each call of `foo` I need to consume a certain chunk of the main buffer to construct stuff in `foo`. So the next call to `foo` must start from where the last one ended... It's debatable whether I should pass `end` by reference though...

Comment: I would pass both by value and return the updated start by value. That's how many STL algorithms do it.

Comment: @Fred, except `advance` - which always annoys the hell out of me... Anyways, I did indeed change the approach...

Comment: @Nim: Oh yeah, it would be quite nice if `advance` were more "functional"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that you have a `std::vector<T>::iterator`, then it is safe to do `&*it`.

Note, however, that it is not safe to convert this to `unsigned long long *`, as the alignment requirements will be different.

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting, I didn't realise that you could obtain the address like that - I guess it is returning a reference to the character rather than a copy... I did say "not safe operation" :), but I'm going to assume (yes, mother of all effups), that on linux this will not be a problem...

Comment: @Nim: It's guaranteed to work; as long as the iterator is valid your pointer is valid.

Comment: Are you sure the cast is not safe because of alignment issues? I've always though that the most common cause for something like that to fail are aliasing issues. Of course, reinterpret_cast behavior is only rarely defined anyways...

Comment: @ltjax: Yes, aliasing causes issues as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a pointer to start of your vector using `&(*start)`. From there on, you can use pointer arithmetic. But what's that about `unsigned long long*`?

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis though.